# How to reuse styles defined in a parent ContentView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Fist, I have a component called `FieldView` defined in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="CustomViews.Components.Fields.FieldView">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hello world" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"></Label>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```

The `FieldView` component has a style named "LabelStyle". Obviously I can use this style inside `FieldView` component. But this component is a base component that will be inherited by other components, like `TextFieldView`, implemented as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<local:FieldView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GeoSapiens.Coletum.CustomViews.Components.Fields"
    x:Class="GeoSapiens.Coletum.CustomViews.Components.Fields.TextFieldView">

    <StackLayout>

        <!-- the style is not accessible here -->
        <Label Text="Hello from TextFieldView" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"></Label>

    </StackLayout>

</local:FieldView>
```

The problem is that I cannot use the style defined in the `FieldView` inside the `TextFieldView` component.

Is there a way that I can reference styles defined in my `FieldView`  inside `TextFieldView` component? That is: access a style defined in parent component. Should I use the code-behind file in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick's answer really works, it's just a syntax mistake that I can't imagine how your app is running on with it...

However, you'll be able to extend the styles (and any other resource) if you create a method to provide the `ResourceDictionary` instead of defining it on XAML. So your base view will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CustomViews.Components.Fields.FieldView">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hello world" 
               Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

And then, in the code behind you should implement and use the method to get the resources dictionary:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class FieldView : ContentView
{
    public FieldView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Here you set the Resources property through your method
        Resources = GetResources();
    }

    protected virtual ResourceDictionary GetResources()
    {
        ResourceDictionary ret = new ResourceDictionary();

        // Create your style here
        Style labelStyle = new Style(typeof(Label));
        labelStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = Label.FontSizeProperty, Value = 20 });

        // Add the style to Resource Dictionary
        ret.Add("LabelStyle", labelStyle);

        // Return the resource Dictionary
        return ret;
    }
}
```

In your child view you should set the `Resources` property just like you did on base and add new resources as much as you need:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ChildView : FieldView
{
    public ChildView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Call the same method
        Resources = GetResources();
    }

    protected override ResourceDictionary GetResources()
    {
        ResourceDictionary res = base.GetResources();

        // You can add new Styles here, for example
        Style newStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
        newStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = Button.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Color.Red });

        res.Add("DangerButtonStyle", newStyle);

        return res;
    }
}
```

I hope it would be useful.

Comment: Hi Diego! In fact my answer has an typo error, but my code does not. The error come from the copy & paste & edit process while creating the question. Strangely my code worked after a rebuild process. I'm accepting your answer because your tip about `GetResources` method best fit my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using that same `Style` in multiple views throughout your entire app I would probably just move your style into your `App.xaml` and use it from there.

However, what you are trying to do should work if `TextFieldView` base class is set to `FieldView` but it looks like from your code your resource isn't properly defined in it and is missing a closing `</Style>`. For example, the code below worked when I tried it out and used `TextFieldView` in a xaml page.

FieldView:

```
<ContentView 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="TestApp.Forms.FieldView">
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hello world" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

TextFieldView:

```
<local:FieldView 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NuclearHalfLife.Forms" 
    x:Class="TestApp.Forms.TextFieldView">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hello from TextFieldView" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
    </StackLayout>
</local:FieldView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a separate ResourceDictionary from a new Content Page and use [Merged Resource Dictionaries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries/#Merged_Resource_Dictionaries):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="MyNamespace.MyStyles">
  <Style x:Key="LabelResDictStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Hello from ResDictStyle" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Redefine the code behind:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class MyStyles : ResourceDictionary
  {
    public MyStyles()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

The style in the separate resource dictionary can be referenced in the `ContentView`:

```
xmlns:resDictStyles="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
...
<ContentView.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <resDictStyles:MyStyles />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
...
<Label Style="{StaticResource LabelResDictStyle}" />
```

The style from the merged resource dictionary can be "extended" using `BasedOn`:

```
xmlns:resDictStyles="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
...
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <resDictStyles:MyStyles />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style x:Key="LabelPageStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource LabelResDictStyle}">
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
    </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Label Style="{StaticResource LabelPageStyle}" />
```